# Union of two arrays of objects by merging on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to merge two sets of arrays of objects according to some conditions on each set. If a `keyword` on `array1` is not found on `array2` then add the object from `array1` and add the property value pair `number: 0`, if it is found then juts add the properties of `array1` to `array2` object.

This is how far I got, but keeps on repeating the objects.

```js
const array1 = [
  { keyword: 'present', prop: 'foo' },
  { keyword: 'another present', prop: 'bla' },
  { keyword: 'not present', prop: 'hey' }
]

const array2 = [
  { keyword: 'present', number: 12345 },
  { keyword: 'another present', number: 12345 }
]

const res = array1.reduce((acc, obj1) => {
  for (const obj2 of array2) {
    if (obj2.keyword === obj1.keyword) {
      acc.push({
        ...obj1,
        ...obj2
      })
    } else {
      acc.push({
        ...obj1,
        number: 0
      })
    }
  }

  return acc
}, [])

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

This is the desired output

```
[
  { keyword: 'present', prop: 'foo', number: 12345 },
  { keyword: 'another present', prop: 'bla', number: 12345 },
  { keyword: 'not present', prop: 'hey', number: 0 }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break from the loop early as soon as one match is found.

```
const res = array1.reduce((acc, obj1) => {
  for (const obj2 of array2) {
    if (obj2.keyword === obj1.keyword) {
      acc.push({
        ...obj1,
        ...obj2
      })
      return acc // as soon as obj2 is found, stop processing for obj1
    }
  }

  acc.push({
    ...obj1,
    number: 0
  }) // if nothing from array2 is found

  return acc
}, [])
```

Comment: Thanks, works great, I actually fixed it by creating a hash table with the array2 and then reduce on the array1.